# My code is not showing Adjacency List for a Graph

Tags: java, graph, linked-list

I'm very much new in java. I'm trying to read a .txt file which has input for Graph and I need to create another file which will show the output of that Graph (Adjacency List & Matrix for both directed and undirected Graph). I'm able to create the output of Adjacency matrix perfectly but it's not showing the list properly. 
My .txt file looks as below:

```
7

10

0 1 2 4 3 5 6 5 5 3 2 3 5 0 6 2 0 4 1 5
```

Here is my code

```
public class Node{
    int element;
    Node next;

    public Node(int elem, Node n){
        element = elem;
        next    = n;
    }
}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class graph {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner scn = new Scanner(new File("D:/raj.txt"));

    int numVertices = scn.nextInt();
    int numEdges    = scn.nextInt();

    int [][] adMatrix = new int [numVertices][numVertices];
    Node  [] adList   = new Node[numVertices];

    for(int i=0; i<numVertices; i++) 
      adList[i] = new Node(i, null);
    for(int i=0; i<numEdges; i++){
      int u = scn.nextInt();
      int v = scn.nextInt();
      adMatrix[u][v] = 1;
      adMatrix[v][u] = 1;
      Node n;
      for(n=adList[u]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) 
        n.next = new Node(v, null);
      for(n=adList[v]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) 
        n.next = new Node(u, null);
    }

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("D:/output using Java.txt"));

    pw.print("Adjacency Matrix:");
    pw.println();
    pw.println();
    for(int i=-1; i<numVertices; i++){
      for(int j=-1; j<numVertices; j++){
        if(i==-1 && j==-1) pw.print("     ");
        else if(i==-1 && j!=-1) pw.print(j + "   ");
        else if(i!=-1 && j==-1) pw.print(i + "    ");
        else                    
          pw.print(adMatrix[i][j] + "   ");
      }
      if(i==-1) 
        pw.println();
      pw.println();
    }
    pw.println();

    pw.print("Adjacency List:");
    pw.println();
    pw.println();
    for(int i=0; i<numVertices; i++){
      pw.print(i + " ");
      pw.println();
      pw.print(adList[i].element+ "------>");
       for(Node n = adList[i].next; n!=null; n=n.next){
        pw.print(n.element);
        if(n.next!=null) 
          pw.print("--->");
        else             
          pw.println();
      }

      }

    pw.close();

  }
}
```

Output file looks like:

```
Adjacency Matrix:

     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   

0    0   1   0   0   1   1   0   
1    1   0   0   0   0   1   0   
2    0   0   0   1   1   0   1   
3    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   
4    1   0   1   0   0   0   0   
5    1   1   0   1   0   0   1   
6    0   0   1   0   0   1   0   

Adjacency List:
0 
0------>1 
1------>2 
2------>3 
3------>4 
4------>5 
5------>6 
6------>
```

Adjacency list is not showing properly in the output file. Please help me to get the Adjacency list right.. :)

Comment: It is most helpful to include your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: You can edit your question to add additional information.  It works better than the comments where you have no formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here will add a new node to each node until it reaches the end. In other words, every time you try to add a new nose, it overwrites what is already there.

```
  for(n=adList[u]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) 
      n.next = new Node(v, null);
  for(n=adList[v]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) 
      n.next = new Node(u, null);
```

Try this instead. To traverse to the end of the list, the only statement in your loop should be the one that advances to the next item. Also, the use of `while` makes the intention of the loop more clear (IMO).

```
n = adList[u];
while (n.next!=null) n=n.next;
n.next= new Node(v, null);
```

Also, it seems like this section of code might not be doing what you expect.

```
  pw.print(i + " ");
  pw.println();
  pw.print(adList[i].element+ "------>");
```

Based on the output you've shared, I think you may want to delete the newline in the middle. Also, `adList[i].element` probably should not be the same as `i`. But it's happening because you are initializing you adjacency list like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<numVertices; i++) 
    adList[i] = new Node(i, null);
```

Essentially, you are initializing each vertex with an edge that loops to itself. So you have two choices here. You can skip the first node in your list, or you can rewrite it to leave `adList[i]` as null upon initialization. If you choose the second option, then you will need to deal with some annoying edge cases. I'd recommend instead initializing your array with

```
for(int i=0; i<numVertices; i++) 
    adList[i] = new Node(-1, null);
```

so that you have a 'header' node on each list. If you accidentally print the header node it will be obvious because it is -1. Then if you change this

```
  pw.print(i + " ");
  pw.println();
  pw.print(adList[i].element+ "------>");
```

To this:

```
  pw.print(i + " ");
  pw.print( "------>");
```

You'll skip the header node and it should work how you want it to.

------ EDIT ------
Also, the  `println` in this isn't guaranteed to be called.

```
    if(n.next!=null) 
      pw.print("--->");
    else             
      pw.println();
  }
  // move it here
  }
```

You should move it to the end of the outer loop.

Comment: This is definitely a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks all for the help... :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
  for(n=adList[u]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) { /* skipping */ }
    n.next = new Node(v, null);
  for(n=adList[v]; n.next!=null; n=n.next) { /* skipping */ }
    n.next = new Node(u, null);
```

Comment: This fixes the issue with edges not being added, but it looks like there might also be an issue with the list initialization.